# “Connection reset by peer” error occured when new tcp socket

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sockets

The code below aims at making TCP Server and Clients.
But when the number of the client threads is too big(for example: 100 threads), then client receives an "Connection reset by peer" error. I can't find out the cause of the error, so I need your help.

Server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

require "socket"
crab = TCPServer.new "127.0.0.1", 8087
while browser = crab.accept
  Thread.new browser do | client |
    puts client.gets
    client.puts "hello"
    client.close
  end
end
```

Client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
require "socket"
threads_arr = []
ARGV[0].to_i.times do    
  t = Thread.new do
    client = TCPSocket.new "127.0.0.1", 8087
    client.puts "hello"
    client.gets
    client.close
  end  
  threads_arr << t
end
threads_arr.each do | t |
  t.join
end
```

Envrionment:

Mac OS X 10.6.8

ruby 1.8.7p174 / ruby 1.9.2p180

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this be easier to do in [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/)? Threading will only scale so far before it starts to cause trouble. EventMachine also handles load better when receiving a large number of connections.

You may need to check that your accept queue is sufficiently large. The default is something like 5 pending connections and if they can't be acknowledged quickly enough you might have them dropped.

Comment: I see, the problem was that the backlog is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Socket connection should be closed on one side - or client only or server only. In your example if server close connection first client receive exception when try close connection.
Delete for example `close` call in client:

```
  t = Thread.new do
    client = TCPSocket.new "127.0.0.1", 8087
    client.puts "hello"
    client.gets
  end
```

Comment: Thanks to tadman's answer, I find out that the problem was the backlog is too small. when "crab.listen 100" was been inserted after TCPServer.new, the problem was resovled.